# Linear wave theory free surface condition

Tags: fluid-dynamics, boundary-conditions

How does this formula come about, why it is free boundary conditions?
$$\sigma^2\phi-g\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial z}=0.$$
$\sigma$is the angle frequency, $\phi$ is the potential flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's recall that for a potential flow in an incompressible fluid in a gravitational field,
$$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}+\frac{1}{2}v^2+\frac{p}{\rho}+g z=f(t)$$
Second, a small amplitude gravity wave, i.e., $a\ll \lambda$, is described by the above equation. We need to also neglect the $v^2$ term. Redefining $\phi(t)$, we can also set $f(t)=0$. So we arrive at
$$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}+\frac{p}{\rho}-g z=0$$
Now let us suppose the surface of fluid is identified by the following function:
$$\zeta\equiv \zeta(x,y,t)$$

1. It is clear that at surface $p=p_0$, so the above equation simplifies to $p_0=-\rho\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}-\rho g \zeta$ at the surface.
   Again, by redefining $\phi(t)$, we can elliminete $p_0$:
   $$\big(\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}\big)_{sur}+g \zeta=0\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(1)$$
2. Note that $\zeta$ is along there $z$ direction. Let's find $v_z$ of the fluid at the surface in terms of derivatives of $\zeta$:
   $$(v_z)_{sur}=\frac{d z_{sur}}{dt}= \frac{d \zeta}{dt}= \frac{\partial \zeta}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial \zeta x}{\partial x} \big(\frac{dx}{dt}\big)_{sur}+\frac{\partial \zeta y}{\partial y} \big(\frac{dy}{dt}\big)_{sur}$$
   Since the last two terms on the right are smaller then the first term, we can write up to first order:
   $(v_z)_{sur}=\frac{\partial \zeta}{\partial t}$.
   On the other hand, in the potential flow, $v_z=\frac{\partial  \phi}{\partial z}$. Therefore:
   $$\big(\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial z}\big)_{sur}=(v_z)_{sur}= \frac{\partial \zeta}{\partial t}=\big(\text{using} \, (1)\big)=-\left(\frac{1}{g}\frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial t^2}\right)_{sur}$$
   And this becomes what you find just by taking $\phi(x,y,z,t)=\phi(z)\sin(\omega t - k x)$.

Hope this helps.

P.S. See Landau-Lifshitz Vol-6 sections 9-12.

Answer (score 0):

Local equlibrium of vertical component of Newton free fall condition at the surface

```
   mass density * kinematic acceleration   = mass density * gravitational acceleration
```

for a harmonic wave

$$\phi = A \sin(\omega \, t - k x), \quad  \rho \, \partial_{tt} \phi =  g\, \rho  \phi$$

Realistically, athmospheric pressure and fluid surface energy density have to be added to express the total acceleration of the free surface.